# Auto resize video with ffmpeg based on input video resolution

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, terminal

I wrote a Bash script to convert all video files in a directory. Some videos are 1280 x 720 resolution, and others are 720 x 1280.

How can I write a `ffmpeg` command that converts 1280 x 720 videos to 640 x 360 and 720 x 1280 videos to 360 x 640?

Comment: Hi Masoud, please provide what you have so far. Then it's easier to work towards a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic syntax is

```
ffmpeg -i in -vf scale=iw/2:-2 out
```

The scale filter will halve the input width, scale the height proportionally and ensure it is even.